# How to display progress of another command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I need help with a bash script I run like this:

`do_something > file.txt` (I'm using the third line of this file.txt in another echo output)

Now I need to get a number of characters on the second line of the file.txt.
(There are only dots - ".")

I can get the number of characters with this command:

`progress=$(awk 'NR==2' file.txt | grep -o \. | wc -w)`

But the problem is, that the file.txt and the number of characters on the second line is "progress bar" so it's changing in time from 0 - XY (i.e. 100) characters.
I want to use it to see a progress in percentage: `echo -ne "$progress % \\r"`

How could I do that in a loop? `do_something > file.txt` must start just once. In next ~5-20 seconds it's printing dots on the second line and I have to take this number updated every second to my output echo "XY %".

How can I read from file.txt every second and find there "new/updated" count of  characters?* < *edit*

*edit:*
* it's real-time process. My do_something > file.txt is "printing" dots to this file and I want print result saved in $progress in real-time. So first command is printing dots to file and I'm counting them in real-time every second and print how many percent is done from 0-100 %

Comment: When do you want to stop the printing?

Comment: I would stop printing when second line of file.txt reach 100 characters.

Comment: See my updated answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30396366/4408382) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is run `do_something > file.txt` in the background and then monitor it. You can use the special `kill` signal `0` to do this.

```
do_something > file.txt &
PID=$!
while kill -0 $PID 2> /dev/null
do
    [calculate percent complete]
    [display percent complete]
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is working too and looks effecient in the code. Now I understand that I have to start do_something > file.txt in the background :-) how simple, thank you. @Mort

Answer (score 1):

First, you should run your command in the background:

```
do_something > file.txt &
```

Then you can watch the changes in the output file. This will infinitely print the second line of `file.txt` every second.

```
while true; do sed -n '2p' < file.txt; sleep 1; done
```

If you want to print only how many characters are on the second line, you can do this:

```
while true; do sed -n '2p' < file.txt | wc -m; sleep 1; done
```

If you want to stop when there is 100 characters on the second line, you can do this:

```
MAX="100"
CUR="0"
while [ $CUR -lt $MAX ]; do CUR=`sed -n '2p' < sprint | wc -m`; echo $CUR; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Thanks!! I used it in this form and it's working!                                                                                                      ssh do_something > file.txt | while [ $CUR -lt $MAX ]; do CUR=`sed -n '2p' < spray.txt | wc -m`; echo -ne "$CUR %" \\r; sleep 1; done